# Check if string starts with tab

Tags: groovy

How do I check if a string starts with a tab in Groovy?

Comment: The character for a tab is: `\t`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This are some ways to do it....there are more like regex

```
​def s = "\t"​​

assert s[0] == "\t"
assert s.startsWith("\t")
```